# SSIS package execution error - Remote FTPS

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssis, ftps

I am trying to run a SSIS package on Server1 which goes and downloads a XML file from a FTPS server. This XML file is actually encoded and carries data which are to be moved to the database in Server1.

When I run the SSIS package I receive the following error:
Error: The script threw an exception: The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,39,11,186)
Task Download Dataupdate file from FTPS server failed

Any idea on what could be the reason behind this error?

Note: I am directly running the SSIS package when I am logged into the server1.

Comment: has this package previously worked?

Comment: No, it never worked on the environment where we were trying to implement. The issue was because of a firewall that blocked download of file.
Thanks for trying to sort this out Nonym!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message was because of the firewall issue. There was a firewall which was assuming that the encrypted xml file was harmful and so blocked download of it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Natively i don't believe SSIS supports SFTP, only regular FTP - you would need a 3rd party control for this to work

Comment: FTPS and SFTP are different actually. We also thought SSIS and a FTPS needs a 3rd party control like WinSCP to get it implemented. Unfortunately we were wrong and we have also implemented a sample at the moment which is working in a LIVE environment without any 3rd party tool. Here is the link on how to get this done.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=VS.90).aspx 
Also the above error was because of a firewall issue which has been sorted out now.